# solving recaptcha without a form submit/ button click ( uses callback )

Tags: javascript, node.js, recaptcha, puppeteer

im trying to solve a recaptcha from a website im trying to scrape

usually the way it works is , captcha is inside a form , i'll send the captcha data to a solving captcha api (im using DBC)  , they return a token

i put the token inside captcha input `(#g-recaptcha-response)` and even tho the green check doesn't show up when i submit the form it will get accepted

but this website automatically shows the information i want to **scrape** as soon as captcha is solved in another way when the green check of captcha shows up , the page get updated with new information

so my question is when i put the token inside captcha input is there any way to trigger captcha solved event (or whatever happens when green  check shows up .. im guessing some sort of callback ) without submitting the form ?

edit :

by exploring recaptcha configuration exploring i found this

```
___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback
```

which points to this

```
function verifyCallback(e)
```

but im not sure how to invoke it

```
async function init_puppeteer() {

    const global_browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false     , slowMo : 10 ,  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox' , ]});
    const page = await global_browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
    await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 1500});

    try {


        await page.goto('https://example.com', {timeout: 60000})
            .catch(function (error) {
                throw new Error('TimeoutBrows');
            });

        await page.waitForSelector('input[name="url"]');
        await page.type('input[name="url"]', 'example.com' , {delay: 10})
        await page.click('button.css-117i75i-button');
        await page.waitForSelector('#g-recaptcha' ,{visible : true });
        const datakey = await page.$eval('#g-recaptcha' , el => el.getAttribute('data-sitekey'));
        const cap = await solvecaptcha(datakey ,page.url() );

        await page.$eval('#g-recaptcha-response', (el  , cap ) => el.value = cap , cap );
        console.log('done!');


    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log('--------ERRRO--------------------------');
        console.log(e);
        await  page.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how you are bypassing the reCAPTCHA, but if having this fully automated is not a "must", you can always interact with the browser by using the 'headless' parameter:   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })

That way, you can fill it manually and then continue with your scraping script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found the answer , just in case anyone has this problem just in your browser console play with this object `___grecaptcha_cfg` to find the callback mine was here

```
___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback
```

but it can have different structure for other websites

so basically after i recived the token and put it in the #g-recaptcha-response` i called this function and passed the token as argument

```
    let js = `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback("${cap}")`;
    await page.evaluate(js);
```

Comment: You genius @hretic  -> how did you know to look at `___grecaptcha_cfg`. Also for me it was in `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].D.D.callback()`

Comment: ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].A.A.callback()  work for me

Comment: bro is this recaptcha v3 is there a way for this in python cuz I am also trying to bypass this using the anchor url but the "
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LeTyx4pAAAAADdxekqYu48i5QZOJ-kMFp7UUfky&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYXlnby5sazo0NDM.&hl=en&v=u-xcq3POCWFlCr3x8_IPxgPu&size=invisible&cb=vwqr4tapsnh3 "      here the cb which is the callback it changes everytime when the captcha loads. do u know way for this too